# Database Normalisation and Searching it Quickly

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm working on the technical architecture for a content solution integration.  The data from the solution provider runs to millions of rows and normalised to 3NF.  It is updated on a regular schedule (daily most likely) and its data is split down to a very granular level of atomicity.

I need to search and query this data and my current inclination is to leave the normalised data alone and create a denormalised database from its data (OLAP to OLTP).  The 'transfer' can be a custom built program that can contain the necessary business logic in addition to the raw copying power and be run at a set schedule as required.  The denormalised database would then reduce the atomicity and allow the keyword searches and queries to run efficiently. I was looking at using [Lucene .NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for the keyword work on the denormalised database.

So before I sing loudly from the hills that this is the way forward, I wanted some expert opinion on this and what is the perceived "best practise".  Is the method I have suggested the best way forward considering the data I will be provided?  It was suggested that perhaps I could use a 'search engine' to search the normalised data. This scared the hell out of me, but raised the question; what search engine and how?

Opinions, flames, bad language and help appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure you have a problem searching the data in its normalized form?  There _are_ databases that can benefit from denormalization for searching but in my experience people are far to quick to assume that they have a performance problem.  Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Larry.  This is all based on MS SQL. I can assure you performing keyword based or semi-complex queries on the normalised data takes an absolute age. Civilizations have come and gone quicker!

Comment: Before going that way I would double check all indexes, FK, and eventually monitor the %processor and %memory. I recently found a nice and free diagnostic tool here: http://sqlcop.lessthandot.com/

Comment: I agree with Larry. Even with millions of rows and loads of tables, if the keys and indexes are setup correctly, queries should be fast. Are you perchance performing joins on varchar fields, or something insanitary like that?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. The data comes from a huge content provider. They are the biggest in the world and the data they provide is wide ranging and the data structure reflects this. Therefore, even they recommend to not run complex queries on the data directly because they are just too slow. And thankfully no JOINs on varchar fields (but I have seen that done in my time I can tell you!) :)

Comment: @dooburt, the question can't be answered as it's currently stated. You need to provide information about the structure of the data, the main query patterns, the estimated data growth, the concurrency levels, the acceptable response times, the level of accuracy in answers needed, and I could go on :)

Comment: @Ronnis, I agree that the question is somewhat vague. Unfortunately, at this stage the information I have is exactly that; vague. I also accept the question is somewhat theoretical and can't be answered 'directly'. The question wasn't intentionally written that way. I suppose I was looking to see if anyone blew my ETL idea out the water completely and called me stupid for even considering such a notion! Seen as no-one has done that, I can mark the question as answered to my satisfaction :) Thank you for the kindness in your response however. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built reporting databases and data warehouses based on data stored in normalized form.  There is quite a bit of work involved in the transfer program (ETL).  Given your description of the data feed, maybe some of that work has been done for you by the feeder.

Millions of rows isn't a lot, these days.  You may be able to get away with report oriented views into the existing database.  Try it and see.

The biggest benefit to building an OLAP oriented database is not speed.  It's flexibility.  "We love this report, but now we want to see it weekly and quarterly instead of monthly. Bam! Done!" "Can you break it down by marketing category instead of manufacturing category?  Bam! Done!" And so on.

Comment: Walter, thanks for the response. An ETL program is my favoured approach based on all the factors here. The OLAP data is to do exactly what you have described, with numerous requests for report a, b, c and d for instance.  I did play with the idea for Materialised Views on the normalised data, but there are factors out-of-control that make them an unlikely solution.

Answer (score 0):

A resonably normalized model (3NF/BCNF) provides the best average performance and the least amount of modification anomalies for the largest number of scenarios. That's big, so I would start from there. As your requirements are fuzzy, it's seems like the most sensible option.

Actually, the most sensible thing would be to go over the requirements until they are a bit more "crisp" ;)

Also, if you could get your hands on a few early extracts from your data provider you could experiment with it and get a feeling for the data distributions (not all people live in one country, and some countries holds more people than others. Not all people have children, and the number children per person is vastly different depending on the country). This is a major point and it is crucial that the optimizer can make good decisions.

Other than that, I agree with everything Walter said and also gave him my vote.